# Error creating heatmap. ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to create a heatmap using hist2d. I have (x,y) coordinates and z values with a probability of this points.

```
x = list(range(1920))
y = list(range(1080))
z = np.zeros((1920, 1080))

plt.hist2d(x,y, bins = 256, weights=z)

VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_heatmap3.py", line 109, in <module>
    plt.hist2d(x,y, bins = 50, weights=z)
  File "/home/wojtek/_mgr/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2849, in hist2d
    **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "/home/wojtek/_mgr/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1352, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "/home/wojtek/_mgr/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 7073, in hist2d
    density=density, weights=weights)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in histogram2d
  File "/home/wojtek/_mgr/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py", line 713, in histogram2d
    hist, edges = histogramdd([x, y], bins, range, normed, weights, density)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in histogramdd
  File "/home/wojtek/_mgr/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/histograms.py", line 1049, in histogramdd
    smin, smax = _get_outer_edges(sample[:,i], range[i])
  File "/home/wojtek/_mgr/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/histograms.py", line 322, in _get_outer_edges
    if not (np.isfinite(first_edge) and np.isfinite(last_edge)):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: What's the code that's failing?

Comment: plt.hist2d(x,y, bins = 256, weights=z)

Comment: A few days ago I was programming in JavaScript and receiving a 'not a function' error. I thought it was a problem with the function definition but it was actually because I had the wrong number of arguments. So the error might not be in the line it throws.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what the `hist2d` plot does and what sort of input it expects. You don't get to construct the grid, that's what `hist2d` does. You should simply supply the datapoints `w_i(x_i, y_i)` that the histogram accumulates. Matplotlibs documentation:

> weights   array-like, shape (n, ), optional
>
> An array of values w_i weighing each sample (x_i, y_i).

```py
x = np.random.rand(10000) * 1920
y = np.random.rand(10000) * 1080
w = np.random.rand(10000)
plt.hist2d(x, y, weights=w)
plt.show()
```